# Подключение оплаты на сайт WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Мне нужно подключить paypal-платеж к моему сайту wordpress. Для этого я использую https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-paypal/. После оплаты должна сработать хранимая процедура в  Functions.php

```
function wp_paypal_order_processed_action( $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("CALL ExtendLicense('1@gmail.com', 30, 300, '2018-06-12')");
    $wpdb->query('COMMIT');
}
```

Как сделать чтобы в нее параметры передавались из полей, расположенных на странице оплаты: email, сумма и тд.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак, потому что `wp_paypal_order_processed_action()` срабатывает, когда PayPal отправляет POST-запрос на ваш сайт после успешной оплаты.

WordPress инициализируется снова, никакой "вашей страницы" для сервера уже не существует. Вам надо сохранять эти поля при создании заказа, а потом уже использовать их после оплаты.

**UPDATE**

Все еще хуже. Этот плагин создаёт заказ в процессе обработки ответа от PayPal. Вот в WooCommerce, например, сделано правильно - сначала создаётся заказ, записывается в базу, а потом уже идёт обращение к платёжным системам, например, PayPal. Там можно внести какие-то свои данные в заказ, а после получения ответа с ними работать.

Чтобы работать с этим примитивным плагином, вам придётся вести свой учёт заказов, где-то в базе сохранять данные заказа отдельно от данных плагина.

Работали бы сразу с WooCommerce, таких проблем бы не возникло.

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: Дополнил ответ...